# When typing ctrl-c in a terminal, why isn't the foreground job terminated until it completes?

Tags: bash, signals

To understand

> **If Bash is waiting for a command to complete** and receives a signal for
>   which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the
>   command completes.
>
> **When Bash is waiting for an asynchronous command via the wait builtin**,
>   the reception of a signal for which a trap has been set will cause the
>   wait builtin to return immediately with an exit status greater than
>   128, immediately after which the trap is executed.

from Bash manual,
I run the following:

1. In my two examples, SIGINT (sent with Ctrl-C) terminates a
   foreground job (the first case in the quote) and a background job
   (the second case in the quote) both immediately, without waiting for
   them to complete.

   Does the first sentence in the quote mean that if Bash is running a
   foreground job and receives signal `SIGINT`, the trap of the signal
   `SIGINT`, when set, will be executed until the command completes? 
   If yes, **why in my first example, does `ctrl-C` make the foreground
   job exists immediately before it can complete?**

   ```
   $ sleep 10000  # a foreground job
   ^C


   $ sleep 10000 & # a background job
   [1] 21219
   $ wait 21219
   ^C
   $ echo $?
   130
   ```
2. What does **"a signal for which a trap has been set"**  mean,

   - a signal `arg` whose trap has been specified via `trap arg sigspec`,  or
   - a signal which is not ignored,  or
   - a signal whose trap isn't the default one?

   In the examples in my part 1, I didn't set up a trap for SIGINT, so the signal has its
   default handler (which breaks out of any executing loop). Is a
   **signal having its default handler** considered to have a trap that has
   been set?
3. **I set up a trap for `SIGINT`**, but `ctrl-C` will make the following
   command exit before completing. So is it contrary to the first
   sentence in my quote?

   ```
   $ trap "echo You hit control-C!" INT
   $ bash -c 'sleep 10; echo "$?"'
   ^C
   $
   ```

   **Before setting the trap for `SIGINT`**,    `ctrl-C` will also make the
   same command exit before completing. So is it contrary to the first
   sentence in my quote?

   ```
   $ bash -c 'sleep 10; echo "$?"'
   ^C
   ```
4. Could you give some examples to explain what the two sentences in
   the quote mean?

Thanks.

Comment: You’re not setting any traps, so your tests don’t check the behaviour described in your quote.

Comment: The subject line doesn't mention traps, but the quoted part of the manual is about traps, but-but the rest of the question sets up no traps; are we setting up traps for this question or not?

Comment: @StephenKitt: Thanks. (1) What does "a signal for which a trap has been set" mean? (2) could you give an example which "check the behaviour described in the quote"?

Comment: Made more explanation. Please reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What does "a signal for which a trap has been set" mean?

That's a signal for which a handler has been defined (with `trap 'handling code' SIG`) where the handling code is not empty as that would cause the signal to be ignored.

So signals that have their default disposition are not signals for which a trap has been set.
Some of that quote in your post also applies to signals that have their default disposition, though obviously not the part about *running the trap*, since no trap have been defined for them.

---

The manual talks about signal delivery **to the shell**, not to the commands you run from that shell.

## 1.

> **If Bash is waiting for a command to complete** and receives a signal for which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the command completes.

(1)

> why in my first example, does ctrl-C make the foreground job exit immediately before it can complete

**If you run `sleep 10` at the prompt of an interactive shell**, the shell will put that job in the *foreground* (through an `ioctl()` on the tty device that tells the terminal line discipline which process group is the foreground one), so **only `sleep` will get a SIGINT upon `^C` and the interactive shell will not**, so it's not useful to test that behaviour.

- The parent shell, as it's interactive won't receive the SIGINT as its process is not in the foreground process group.
- Each command is free to handle signals as they please. `sleep` doesn't do anything specially with SIGINT, so will get the default disposition (terminate) unless SIGINT was being ignored upon startup.

(2) **If you run `sleep 10` in a non-interactive shell**,

```
bash -c 'sleep 10; echo "$?"'
```

**Both the noninteractive `bash` shell and `sleep` will receive the SIGINT when you press Ctrl-C.**

If `bash` exited straight away, it could leave the `sleep` command running unattended in background if it happened to ignore or handle the SIGINT signal. So instead,

- `bash` like most other shells, *blocks* the reception of signals (at least some signals) when waiting for commands.
- Delivery is resumed after the command exits (upon which traps are executed).  That also avoids commands in traps to run concurrently with other commands.

In that example above, `sleep` will die upon SIGINT, so `bash` doesn't have long to wait to handle its own SIGINT (here to die as I didn't add a `trap` on SIGINT).

(3)   when you press Ctrl+C while running the noninteractive shell:

```
bash -c 'sh -c "trap \"\" INT; sleep 3"; echo "$?"'
```

(with no `trap` on SIGINT) `bash` is not killed by the SIGINT. `bash`, like a few other shells treat SIGINT and SIGQUIT specially. They implement the *wait and cooperative exit* behaviour described at https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html (and is known to cause a few annoyances like [the scripts calling SIGINT handling commands that can't be interrupted with `^C`](/q/230421/))

(4) To properly test, you should **run a non-interactive `bash`** that **has SIGINT trap set** and calls a **command that doesn't die straight away upon SIGINT** like:

```
bash -c 'trap "echo Ouch" INT; sh -c "trap \"\" INT; sleep 3"'
```

`bash` is waiting for `sh` that has (along with `sleep`) SIGINT ignored (because of the `trap "" INT`), so SIGINT won't kill `sleep` nor `sh`. `bash` does not ignore SIGINT, but its handling is defered until `sh` returns. You see `Ouch` being displayed, not upon <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, but after `sleep` and `sh` have terminated normally.

Note that the `trap` command sets a trap for a signal for the same shell in which it runs.   So  when the `trap` command  is executed outside the noninteractive shell  and in the parent shell,

> ```
> $ trap "echo You hit control-C!" INT
> $ bash -c 'sleep 10; echo "$?"'
> ^C
> $
> ```

the noninteractive `bash`, and `sleep` commands won't inherit that `trap` from the parent shell. Signal handlers are lost upon executing a different command (`execve()` wipes the whole address space of the process including the code of the handler). Upon `execve()`, signals that had a handler defined revert to the default disposition, those that were ignored remain ignored.
In addition to that, in most shells, `trap`s are also reset in sub-shells.

## 2.

> **When Bash is waiting for an asynchronous command via the wait builtin**, the reception of a signal for which a trap has been set will cause the wait builtin to return immediately with an exit status greater than 128, immediately after which the trap is executed.

**When using `wait` explicitly**,  `wait`  is interrupted by any signal that has a trap set (and obviously also those that kill the shell altogether).

That makes it difficult to **get the exit status of a command reliably when there are trapped signals**:

```
$ bash -c 'trap "echo Ouch" INT; sh -c "trap \"\" INT; sleep 10" & wait "$!"; echo "$?"'
^COuch
130
```

In that case, `sleep` and `sh` were not killed by the SIGINT (since they ignore it). Still `wait` returns with a `130` exit status because a signal (SIGINT) was received while it was waiting for `sh`. You'd need to repeat the `wait "$!"` until `sh` really terminates to get `sh`'s exit status.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to understand your reply, and still not sure if I understand. When I run `bash -c 'sleep 10; echo "$?"'` with the trap for SIGINT is set, `ctrl-C` will make it exit before completing. So is it contrary to the first sentence in my quote?

Comment: I have updated my post with more information.

Comment: @Tim, see edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Sorry for taking the liberty to change the organization of your reply. As I still not yet completely understand, I might made some mistakes when editing. So please correct mine if you find some.

Comment: Because the first sentence from the bash manual quote says "If Bash is ... and receives a signal for which a trap has been set", I understand it is necessary to set the trap in the noninteractive shell, as in `bash -c 'trap "echo Ouch" INT;...'`. Some questions: (1) What is the purpose of the other trap set in the same shell as `sleep`, i.e. the trap in `sh -c "trap \"\" INT; sleep 3"`?  (2)  In "you should run a non-interactive bash that calls a command that intercepts SIGINT ", does "a command that intercepts SIGINT" mean `sh -c "trap \"\" INT; sleep 3"` in the example?

Comment: (3)  in the two examples in parts 1(2) and 1(3) that I created in your reply, there is no SIGINT trap set in the noninteractive bash shell. So shouldn't the noninteractive bash shell behave in the same way, instead of behaving differently: ignores SIGINT it receives in part 1(2), while having the wait and cooperative exit behaviour  in part 1(3)?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! When running `bash -c 'trap "echo Ouch" INT; sh -c "trap \"\" INT; sleep 3"'`,  all three processes `bash`, `sh` and `sleep`  receive SIGINT. Is there an order between the three processes about which handles SIGINT before which, and does one's handling depend on previous one's handling? Shouldn't `sleep` exit right away on receiving SIGINT?  So why "SIGINT won't kill `sleep` nor `sh`"?

Comment: I see. it is because the parent shell `sh` of `sleep 3` has set up a trap to ignore SIGINT via `trap \"\" INT; `. Sorry for my stupid question.

Comment: @Tim, yes, `sh` and `sleep` will receive but _ignore_ SIGINT. That's what `trap "" INT` does: set the signal disposition to SIG_IGN (inherited by child processes and preserved upon `execve()`). `bash`'s own handling of SIGINT is deferred until `sh` returns.