# How are the processes involved when we send a signal using control keys or running `kill`?

Tags: bash, terminal, process, signals, ipc

A signal is sent by or from a process to another process.

A `bash` process is usually run in a terminal emulator process such as gnome terminal.

A `bash` process in turn runs other processes.

So when we send  a signal to a process using control keys or running `kill` in a terminal emulator which runs `bash`, which process sends the signal to which process? how are th terminal emulator process, the bash process, and the child processes of the bash process involved?

Thanks.

Comment: These are two different things. `kill` sends signals according to the options set for it, and for the control keys, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work

Comment: See also [What are the responsibilities of each Pseudo-Terminal (PTY) component (software, master side, slave side)?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/120071)

Comment: See also (for general reference): [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty', and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/80216)

Answer (score 2):

When executing the `kill` commands that are built-in to various shells, it is the shell process itself that is executing the system call to send the signal.

When executing an external `kill` command, it is the process forked to run that program that is executing the system call to send the signal.

There is no such thing as "a pseudo terminal process".  [Pseudo terminals are not processes.](https://superuser.com/a/723442/38062)  There is a *terminal emulator* process, but that emulator is not the pseudo terminal.

When a special character is sent from a terminal, or from a terminal emulator via the master side of a pseudo-terminal, to the line discipline in the kernel, then (assuming that the line discipline has the terminal in canonical input mode where special characters are special) it is the kernel that sends the signal.

## Further reading

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302350/
- [What are the responsibilities of each Pseudo-Terminal (PTY) component (software, master side, slave side)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117981/)

Comment: terminal delivery upon `^C`/`^Z`/... is independent of the _canonical mode_. You need `isig` to be on in the output of `stty -a` for it.

Comment: Thanks. (1) From [my modification of Stephane Chazelas' reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384702/674), "The manual talks about signal delivery to the shell, not to the commands you run from that shell." In that case, what process sends signals to the shell? (2) Also the same reply mentions that, when running `sleep 1000` in a bash interactive shell, `ctrl-C` will send SIGINT to the process running `sleep 1000`. In that case, which process sends SIGINT to the `sleep 1000` process?

Comment: If I understand https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120071 correctly, are the sender of the signals in both (1) and (2) the tty line discipline in the terminal emulator's driver in the kernel?

Comment: `s/terminal( delivery)/signal$1/` above sorry.