# Could you explain the following statements on how nonbuiltin commands started by Bash handles signals?

Tags: bash, signals

From bash manual

> Non-builtin commands started by Bash have signal handlers set to the
>   values inherited by the shell from its parent.
>
> When job control is not in eff ect, asynchronous commands  ignore
>   SIGINT and SIGQUIT in addition to these inherited handlers.
>
> Commands run as a result of command substitution ignore the
>   keyboard-generated job control signals SIGTTIN, SIGTTOU, and SIGTSTP.

I was wondering if someone could give some examples to show what the above mean? Thanks.

Related [When typing ctrl-c in a terminal, why isn't the foreground job terminated until it completes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384691/674)

Answer (score 1):

```
stty tostop
echo bar >&2 & # no output from echo, just from shell job control
fg # now the output is produced
    bar
text=$(echo foo; echo bar >&2) # command substitution in foreground command
    bar
text=$(echo /etc/passwd; echo bar >&2) ; ls -l "$text" &
    bar
fg
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2745 18. Feb 00:36 /etc/passwd
```

The "normal" output of the background command is delayed due to `SIGTTOU` but the output from the command substitution in the background to `stderr` is visible immediately.

**external commands**

```
trap '' HUP
bash
sleep 1234 # PID 23456
```

in a defferent shell

```
kill -HUP 23456 # does not abort sleep
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you also explain and give example for "Non-builtin commands started by Bash have signal handlers set to the values inherited by the shell from its parent"?

Comment: @Tim See the edit.

Comment: Thanks. Why does the quote mention "When job control is not in effect"? In your examples, is job control in effect or not?

Comment: @Tim My example is about `SIGTTOU`, not about job control. Thus that manual statement is not applicable here.