# Why does `trap` passthough zero instead of the signal the process was killed with?

Tags: shell, posix, exit-status, trap

Consider the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo $?' INT
kill -INT $$
```

Output: `0`

Here I would expect `130` for my system. Of course, if I do a `Ctrl + C` then I get `130`.

The same thing happens for any other signal like `HUP` or `TERM`. I found this behavior surprising because if you have a `trap` set up to capture many signals then there's no way to exit with the correct error code for what signal called your handler:

```
#!/bin/dash

exit_abrupt() {
    exit_code=$?
    echo "Encountered an error, cleaning up..." >&2
    # *clean up*

    exit "$exit_code" # This will return 0!
}

trap exit_abrupt HUP INT TERM
kill -HUP $$
```

I've tested Bash, Dash, and ZSH, all of which exhibit this behavior. Is this how it's supposed to work across shells? Is it documented by POSIX (can someone point to the documentation)? How else can I know the correct exit code that works across shells?

The best [POSIX documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/trap.html) I've found reads:

> The value of "$?" after the trap action completes shall be the value it had before trap was invoked.

which to me sounds like it should be passing though the signal in all cases and yet it's not so I must be missing something...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$?` contains the exit status of the last command that was run and waited for. You'll find that in:

```
$ bash -c 'trap "echo \$?" INT; sleep 10; exit'
^C130
```

130 was reported because both `sleep` and `bash` received SIGINT upon ^C, bash ran the handler after `sleep` returned and printed the exit status of that `sleep` command.

In:

```
$ bash -c 'trap "echo \$?" INT; kill -s INT "$$"; exit'
0
```

You get the exit status of the `kill` command which was the last command bash ran before the SIGINT handler was invoked.

```
$ bash -c 'trap "echo \$?" INT; (trap "" INT; sleep 3; exit 123); exit'
^C123
```

`sleep` ignores SIGINT, you'll see that upon pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, you still have to wait for the subshell running `sleep` to return at which point the handler prints the exit status of that subshell (123).

If you want to install the same handler for several signals, you can pass the signal to the handler:

```
handler() {
  local signal="$1"
  echo "I got $signal signal"
}
for signal in INT HUP TERM QUIT; do
  trap "handler $signal" "$signal"
done
```

BTW, you'll find that:

```
bash -c '(trap "" INT; sleep 3; exit 123); exit'
```

Exits with a 123 exit status even when you try to interrupt it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, and that's actually as designed in bash. More on that at [When typing ctrl-c in a terminal, why isn't the foreground job terminated until it completes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384691)

Comment: Thank you for this very informative answer. If you want to exit with the same signal received by the handler then I found this: `kill -s "$signal" -- $$`. Turns out kill is a builtin so this seems like the perfect way to do it (tested across Bash, Dash, and ZSH). Don't try the `kill -l -- INT` method because I found that doesn't work on Dash. With `--` is the most portable variant as stated by POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my final solution for combining an `EXIT` trap with a fatal signal trap (whether received by keystroke or a signal sent to the shell process) while always passing through the correct exit status in case anyone wants:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/752570/why-does-trap-passthough-zero-instead-of-the-signal-the-process-was-killed-wit
handle_exit() {
    exit_code=$?
    signal="$1"

    if [ "$exit_code" != 0 ] || [ "$signal" ]; then
        echo "\nProgram was exited abruptly!" >&2
    fi

    # Or do clean up here...

    if [ "$exit_code" != 0 ]; then
        trap -- - EXIT
        exit "$exit_code"
    elif [ "$signal" ]; then
        trap -- - "$signal"
        kill -s "$signal" -- $$
    fi
}

# POSIX sh doesn't include signals in its EXIT trap so list them ourselves
# SIG prefixes removed for POSIX sh compatibility
for signal in HUP INT TERM; do
    # shellcheck disable=SC2064
    trap "handle_exit $signal" "$signal"
done
trap handle_exit EXIT

# Your code starts here...
```

The `trap -- - EXIT` is necessary because if you trigger a literal `INT` (`Ctrl + C`) then the `INT` trap will rightfully go off before the `EXIT` trap. In this particular case (because of the literal `Ctrl + C`), `$exit_code` will also be set to `130`. So, we remove remove the `EXIT` trap from the `if` branch to avoid triggering the handler twice. Similarly, `trap -- - "$signal"` avoids recursively calling the handler forever until stack overflow occurs.

Across all the shells (even Posh), it works like a charm.